# Running single java thread is faster than main?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

im doing a few concurrency experiments in java.
I have this prime calculation method, which is just for mimicking a semi-expensive operation:

```
static boolean isprime(int n){
    if (n == 1)
        return false;
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! flag;
}
```

And then I have this main method, which simply calculates all prime number from 0 to N, and stores results in a array of booleans:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 100_000;
    int T = 1;

    boolean[] bool = new boolean[N];
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(T);

    final int partition = N / T;


    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++ ){
        boolean res = isprime(j);
        bool[j] = res;
    }            
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
}
```

This gives me results like: 893888901 n/s 848995600 n/s

And i also have this drivercode, where I use a executorservice where I use one thread to do the same:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 100_000;
    int T = 1;

    boolean[] bool = new boolean[N];
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(T);

    final int partition = N / T;

    long start = System.nanoTime();


    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++ ){
        final int current = i;
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = current*partition; j < current*partition+partition; j++ ){
                    boolean res = isprime(j);

                    bool[j] = res;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    es.shutdown();
    try {
        es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("what?");
    }

    System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
}
```

this gives results like: 9523201 n/s , 15485300 n/s.

Now the second example is, as you can read, much faster than the first. I can't really understand why that is? should'nt the exercutorservice thread (with 1 thread) be slower, since it's basically doing the work sequentially + overhead from "awaking" the thread, compared to the main thread?

I was expecting the executorservice to be faster when I started adding multiple threads, but this is a little counterintuitive.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are not using the results of the prime calculation; you are storing them in an array and you are not printing them to e.g. System.out. The JIT could see this as dead code and delete all the calculations. 

If you want to microbenchmark, please look at JMH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the timeout at the bottom of your code. If you set that higher you arrive at pretty similar execution times.

`es.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

The execution times you mention for the first main are much higher than the millisecond you allow the second main to wait for the threads to finish.

Comment: thanks will give it a go, but its'nt that a somewhat artificial component of benchmarking? if I just set some delay higher, then the executorservice will slower?

Comment: You just stop waiting for it - it likely wasn't finsihed executing before the time was measured.